# Referring to different MySQL queries in the same PHP website

Tags: php, mysql

I am starting out using MySQL on PHP websites...

I have 2 divs that I am pulling information into, I am pulling `service` and `price` where the id equals `0` in to each one.

I can do this fine, however I have now got to do this in 3 more containers divs, each with 2 divs).

I have attempted to put the SELECT query on top of each div as show below, however this did not work.

I am trying to keep the MySQL Table clean without using `service1`, `service2`, `service3` etc, instead use the id to refer.

Do I need to refer to the id in the echo, or something else?

Here is some of the code...

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT service, price FROM Australia WHERE id = '0'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>

   <div class="container-top">
    <div class="module-service"><span><?php echo $row['service']; ?></span></div>
    <div class="module-price">&pound;<?php echo $row['price']; ?><small> inc VAT </small></div>
   <div>
    <?php $conn->close(); } ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT service, price FROM Australia WHERE id = '1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>

   <div class="container-mid">
    <div class="module-service"><span><?php echo $row['service']; ?></span></div>
    <div class="module-price">&pound;<?php echo $row['price']; ?><small> inc VAT </small></div>
   <div>
    <?php $conn->close(); } ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT service, price FROM Australia WHERE id = '2'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>

   <div class="container-mid">
    <div class="module-service"><span><?php echo $row['service']; ?></span></div>
    <div class="module-price">&pound;<?php echo $row['price']; ?><small> inc VAT </small></div>
   <div>
    <?php $conn->close(); } ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT service, price FROM Australia WHERE id = '3'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>

   <div class="container-bottom">
    <div class="module-service"><span><?php echo $row['service']; ?></span></div>
    <div class="module-price">&pound;<?php echo $row['price']; ?><small> inc VAT </small></div>
   <div>
    <?php $conn->close(); } ?>
```

Comment: You're calling `$conn->close()` in each loop. That means you can't use `$conn` for the next query.

Comment: Don't use `$conn->close()` until you're done with all MySQL queries in the script.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do a separate query for each `id`. Use a single query like `SELECT service, price FROM Australia ORDER BY id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the connection at the very end of the script, not repeatedly. After the first close, the other queries won't work, because the connection will have been closed. It's like walking into a shop that just closed to buy something after someone else purchased something ;)

Also, you have no need to create all those loops, you already have a unique ID for each one, so use it and sort by the ID in ascending order (ASC).

Grab the ID so you can use it. Since you only seem to be changing the class, you can change that in the loop itself, less code duplication then. Only one place to update when you need to change something.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT service, price, id FROM Australia ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($row['id'] == 1)
{
$container = 'top';
}
if ($row['id'] == 2)
{
$container = 'middle';
}
if ($row['id'] == 1)
{
$container = 'bottom';
}
    ?>

   <div class="container-<?php echo $container; ?>">
    <div class="module-service"><span><?php echo $row['service']; ?></span></div>
    <div class="module-price">&pound;<?php echo $row['price']; ?><small> inc VAT </small></div>
   <div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to add `CASE` into the code? For example if there is no price in the table then show `00`?

Comment: Of course, just make a var like $price, if the db price is set then set it otherwise make it 00, a simple if will do.

Comment: Struggling to get this working... Can you give me a bit more advice? :)

Comment: Something like $price = "00"; if ($row['price'] > 0){ $price = $row['price']; } then echo $price instead of the database one by default